Why a $O$-monoidal functor between $O$-monoidal $\infty$-categories $C^{\otimes}$ and $D^{\otimes}$ is a relative right Kan extension along $C$?
Let $O^{\otimes}$ be an $\infty$-operad.
An $O$-monoidal category is a coCartesian fibration $C^{\otimes}\rightarrow O^{\otimes}$. A $O$-monoidal functor between $O$-monoidal categories $p:C^{\otimes}\rightarrow O^{\otimes}$ and $q:D^{\otimes}\rightarrow O^{\otimes}$ is a functor $F:C^{\otimes}\rightarrow D^{\otimes}$ sending $p$-coCartesian arrows to $q$-coCartesian arrows.
Now I wonder whether or not $F$ is a $q$-right Kan extension of $F|_C$ along $C\subseteq C^{\otimes}$. I met this when reading HA.Example.2.1.3.5 and HA.Remark.2.1.3.8.
Thanks for your help.
